# Error 404 github.io

Tags: python, github, github-pages

Как исправить ошибку 404 в github.io в новом репозитории? Пробовал создавать новый, публичный, приватный, менял лицензию, ничего не помогает. в репозитории находится скрипт python для сбора информации, может быть есть какие-то ограничения на github для скриптов python? Это у меня первая такая ошибка, раньше не было, и это первый репозиторий на python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это пофиксило проблему, страница по ссылке работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]